# Angular 6 HTTP Interceptor not setting headers

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to make a jsonwebtoken interceptor and for some reason it doesn't set the header at all.

For my providers I have

```
import { TokenInterceptorService } from './token-interceptor.service';
...
providers: [AuthService, AuthGuard, {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: TokenInterceptorService,
        multi: true
}]
```

as my `TokenInterceptorService` is pretty simple too:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() { }

    intercept(req, next) {

        let tokenizedReq = req.clone({
            setHeader: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer xx.yy.zz'
            }
        })

        return next.handle(tokenizedReq);
    }
}
```

if I log `tokenizedReq` the headers have nothing. I must be overlooking something.

Comment: Is service lazy loaded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not `setHeader` but `setHeaders` - in plural form

```
let tokenizedReq = req.clone({
     setHeaders: {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer xx.yy.zz'
     }
})
```

Comment: Extremely upset at myself as I spent two hours on this. Thank you.

Comment: This is programming :)

Answer (score 2):

`setHeader` is nothing.

Either use `setHeaders: {}` like

```
        let tokenizedReq = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer xx.yy.zz'
            }
        })
```

or use

```
    let tokenizedReq = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization','Bearer xx.yy.zz'),
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the help of Observable.

```js
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {    
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer xx.yy.zz'
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

Comment: I'm quite new to Angular and Typescript. What help do observables give me in this compared to not using them at all like I am now? I've Googled Observables plenty of times, but never really found "why" I'd need it.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular : This link help you to understand what is observable, and what are the advantage of it.